# redux is dispatching prevState value in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a need in my app where I am sending data in child component to parent component onChange of a field, when the child component unmounts I want to send the complete data to redux, and when the child component mounts again, I want to preload it from redux.

In my implementation I am doing this by sending data to parent component, and on unmount I have passed a callback in which parent component dispatches the state to redux, and when child component mounts again, I have used useSelector to get the redux value.

But the problem I am facing is redux is dispatching prevState value rather than updated value. When I unmount the component the second time, updated value is dispatched

I am attaching the codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-with-hooks-forked-hp79o?file=/src/App.js

Steps to reproduce:

Type your name and email in the textbox.
Click on unmount button to unmount the child component.(Dispatched value will be empty)
Click on unmount button again to mount the child component. (Textbox will not be prefilled)
Click on unmount again to unmount. (This time the dispatched value will be name and email which were written)
Click on mount again to mount. (Textbox will be prefilled as values were dispatched this time).

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use combination of useRef and useEffect to make current state changes available to use effect during unmount
This is explained here

https://www.timveletta.com/blog/2020-07-14-accessing-react-state-in-your-component-cleanup-with-hooks/

Updated codesandbox code which works is here
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-with-hooks-forked-gymhl?file=/src/Unmounted.js

Comment: Hey Pavan, thanks for the approach, but I am not sending anything on unmount of component, I am sending data to parent component in every onChange, and I am dispatching data from the parent component during unmount of child component and I am facing problem during the dispatch, I am not accessing data of unmounted component.

Thanks Again